# Fastest way for a HTML page to redirect to a script

Tags: javascript, html, http

**I am looking for fast methods/ways I can redirect a HTML page to another page.**

Currently I use meta-tags to redirect a HTML page to a python script that grabs the website HTML from a SQL database(grabs different HTML based on whether user is on a Mobile device) then sends that HTML back. But this is visibly slow, it shows a blank white page(redirect HTML page) then shows the python script page.

*I know that its not the python script thats slow because if I just go straight to the python script(no redirect from the HTML page) then it loads very fast & with no white screen.*

So for example; someone accesses http://mywebsite.com/contactUs.html which contains only the following HTML:

```
<HTML> <HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; url=cgi-bin/loadWebPage.py?webpage=50002">  </HEAD> </HTML> 
<!-- This redirects to my python script that grabs the contact us HTML & prints it out(shows the webpage HTML) -->
```

Are there other ways a HTML file can redirect to a python script that will be faster?

Maybe I can use HTTP messages? Would the following text/code work in a HTML file?:

```
Status: 301 Moved"
Location:/cgi-bin/loadWebPage.py?webpage=50002
```

Would my last resort be AJAX or javascript to get the fastest result?

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        window.location = 'http://mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/loadWebpage.py?webPage=50001';
    -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place a file called .htaccess in the same directory as your HTML file.  If the file is called "http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html" then .htaccess would contain:

`Redirect permanent /foo/bar.html http://www.example.com/script.py`

Note that the file that gets redirected does not have http://www.example.com, while the file you redirect it to needs the full URL.

If it's your own server, it's a little faster to disable .htaccess files, while instead putting the Redirect command in your httpd.conf file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For the file bar.html in your example, does it need to have any code in that file or should it be empty?

Comment: bar.html doesn't have to contain anything.

Comment: You do this same thing if you want to move a page, a subdirectory, or an entire domain.  The only thing that need exist is a way for Apache to find the .htaccess file.  If you put it at the root of your HTML directory tree, then you don't need any HTML files at all at the original location.

Answer (score 1):

Don Quixote is correct about the .htaccess, I would just like to point out that

http://progtuts.info/198/the-anatomy-of-a-htaccess-file-hints-and-tips/

Will provide some examples and a whole lot of stuff on how to edit your htaccess files etc.

Redirect will definitely work.